# Strange issue at subclassing?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, inheritance

Let's have a class representing a Django controller, with one of methods called `_onSuccess` :

```
class ConfirmController(object):
    ...
    def _onSuccess(self, controller):
      ...
```

The class is instantiated later with:

```
def credit_confirm_info(request, payment_module, template='/some/template.html'):
    controller = ConfirmController(request, payment_module)
    controller.confirm()   # this method calls self._onSuccess
    return controller.response
credit_confirm_info = never_cache(credit_confirm_info)
```

I'm trying to use subclass of ConfirmController:

```
class ConfirmControllerEx(ConfirmController):
    def _onSuccess(self, controller):
        # shortened to demonstrate even simple call to super
        # causes a different behaviour
        super(ConfirmControllerEx, self)._onSuccess(controller)
```

I've probably missed something at python learning but can anybody explain why is **not** the above sublassed `_onSuccess` equivalent to the original method ?
If I do use the above sublass `ConfirmControllerEx`:

```
def credit_confirm_info(request, payment_module, template='/some/template.html'):
    controller = ConfirmControllerEx(request, payment_module)
    controller.confirm()   # this method calls self._onSuccess
    return controller.response
credit_confirm_info = never_cache(credit_confirm_info)
```

I'm getting `NoneType has no method has_header` error, like `credit_confirm_info` is called again but with `request` parameter equal to `None`.

I expect the sublass and subclassed method `_onSuccess` with the plain call to `super` won't differ from the original. Am I missing something here ?

**Update (traceback of the exception):**

```
    Traceback:
File "/home/dunric/Projects/Example.com/satchmo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/dunric/Projects/Example.com/satchmo/gastroceny_cz/localsite/views.py" in cod_confirm_info
  279.             template='shop/checkout/cod/confirm.html')
File "/home/dunric/Projects/Example.com/satchmo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  90.         add_never_cache_headers(response)
File "/home/dunric/Projects/Example.com/satchmo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/cache.py" in add_never_cache_headers
  129.     patch_response_headers(response, cache_timeout=-1)
File "/home/dunric/Projects/Example.com/satchmo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/cache.py" in patch_response_headers
  119.     if not response.has_header('Last-Modified'):

    Exception Type: AttributeError at /checkout/cod/confirm/
    Exception Value: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'has_header'
```

Comment: Can you please paste the *whole* traceback for the exception? The partial exception you posted doesn't appear to have any relationship to your subclass.

Comment: I did pasted whole traceback in an update.

Comment: From the traceback we could have guessed that `controller.response` is `None`, from which we could have lead back to `_onSuccess` not returning anything. But Ben saw it earlier than that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not up on the specifics of django involved here, but this method:

```
def _onSuccess(self, controller):
    # shortened to demonstrate even simple call to super
    # causes a different behaviour
    super(ConfirmControllerEx, self)._onSuccess(controller)
```

Is *not* equivalent to the `_onSuccess` of the parent class. It *calls* the parent implementation through `super`, but it ignores whatever that call returns and just returns `None` (implicitly, by execution reaching the end of the method definition). Given you later get an error that seems to indicate you have a `None` object (instance of `NoneType`) where something else was expected, this would be my guess at the error. That's not going to be it if the contract of the `_onSuccess` method is to always return `None`, however.

Comment: To my excuse I'm a bit spoiled from Ruby's `super` and implicit return value of the last expression. Switching between projects in different languages makes me dizzy sometimes.

Comment: @DavidUnric It's not stupid, just small. :)  All of these kind of tiny details are mostly arbitrary (Does a function with no return result in the last expression? A default "null" value? An exception? A parse error?), so naturally you'll find languages whose designers made different choices. Switching languages often gives you more of these tiny trivial traps to watch out for than real meaningful differences between the languages.